# Changing UIPageViewController own PageController regarding Color of Dots

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, uipageviewcontroller

Hey I'm using a UIPageViewController to control what page I am on and for scrolling. I know it's possible to show a Page Controller along with it by simply adding the following two functions.

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
```

What I want to know is if it's possible to change the color of the page controller, so the dots are more visible on the background I'm using?

I know a regular page controller has the properties:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *currentPageIndicatorTintColor
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *pageIndicatorTintColor
```

However, I can't figure out for the life of me how to access these properties or the Page Controller for that matter from UIPageViewController.

It might be helpful, if someone just said how to change the properties in general?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use UIAppearance to configure UIPageControl colors. This applies to UIPageControls in UIPageViewControllers too.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
  pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: Hi, for tintColor its working. could you tell me how to reduce height of UIPageControl (I have tried `pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(self.viewController.view.bounds.origin.x, self.viewController.view.bounds.origin.y+352, self.viewController.view.bounds.size.width, 10);`)

Comment: Unfortunately this would change the tint color for *all* instances of `UIPageViewController` in the app. What if you want to customize them individually?

Comment: As @devios mentioned, this is an intrusive solution. Anyone know how we can do this specifically for a single UIPageViewController?

Comment: @Zorayr you can use let pageControl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyPageViewController.self])
and begin customizing pageControl

Answer (score 18):

If you would like to change the UIPageControl's colors for a **specific UIPageViewController**, you can use the following:

**In Swift 3**

```
let pageControl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyPageViewController.self])
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green
// ... any other changes to pageControl
```

Answer (score 4):

`UIPageControl` conforms to `UIAppearance` protocol. [The Apple Developper API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance) states about `UIAppearance`:

> Use the `UIAppearance` protocol to get the appearance proxy for a class. You can customize the appearance of instances of a class by sending appearance modification messages to the class’s appearance proxy.

---

Therefore, using Swift 2.2, you may set `UIPageControl`'s `pageIndicatorTintColor` and `currentPageIndicatorTintColor` in a subclass of `UINavigationController` or in your `AppDelegate` class (for a more global approach).

*CustomNavigationController.swift:*

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set pageIndicatorTintColor and currentPageIndicatorTintColor
        // only for the following stack of UIViewControllers
        let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

}
```

*AppDelegate.Swift:*

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // Set pageIndicatorTintColor and currentPageIndicatorTintColor globally
        let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        return true
    }

}
```