# UIPageViewController displaying a black bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIPageViewController` set up to display pages of  `UITableViewController` content. The functionality is working just fine, but the table is hidden at the top and there is a strange black bar at the bottom.

[image: black bar]

So the first thing I did was go to the storyboard and change the settings for my `UIPageViewController` as shown below.

[image: settings]

The resulting view renders like this:

[image: black bar2]

Ideally I would like the pager background to be translucent so that you can see the table below it. Also, although the top of the table is now visible, I don't like how the background has changed to a weird grey/translucent effect. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408269/uipageviewcontroller-page-control-background-color

Answer (score 18):

The color of the `UIPageControl` is already clear. So, what you're seeing is the black background of the `UIPageViewController` peeking through. The problem is that the `UIPageViewController` restricts the size of the view controller to not extend beneath the `UIPageControl`.

Add this following code to your UIPageViewController class to allow your viewController to extend underneath the `UIPageControl`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    //corrects scrollview frame to allow for full-screen view controller pages
    for subView in self.view.subviews {
        if subView is UIScrollView {
            subView.frame = self.view.bounds
        }
    }
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Thank you for saving me hours of headache.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIAppearance` proxy to customize the colors of `UIPageControl`, including the background color.

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

To get rid of translucency of the navigation bar use:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO]
```

Comment: It looks like the `UIPageControl` is transparent by default. I did try setting the backgroundColor to transparent and that didn't help.

Comment: Turns out its the `UIPageViewController` view background color that is showing. However, I want the table that is displayed inside the pageviewcontroller to be displayed beneath the page control.