# Customize UIPageControl indicator for UIPageViewController in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift

I've been looking through various questions/answers on stackoverflow. It seems that its possible to customize the indicators of a page control. Specifically, changing them to custom images.
[Customize dot with image of UIPageControl at index 0 of UIPageControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190147/customize-dot-with-image-of-uipagecontrol-at-index-0-of-uipagecontrol)

However, I am using a UIPageViewController so how can I access the UIPageControl element from within the class? There is no subview that is the UIPageControl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIPageViewController page control background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408269/uipageviewcontroller-page-control-background-color)